# Python for loop not iterating

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through a list of strings and add them to a dictionary if their length equals a length input by the user. When the last loop runs, it only runs one time. I know this because the first word in the dictionary is 8 characters long, and when the user input is 8, it prints just that word, and not the other 8 character words. If the input is 3, an empty dictionary is printed. Why is my loop not iterating through all of the words in the list linelist?

```
wordLength = raw_input("Enter a word length ")
word_dict = {}
infile = open("dictionary.txt")

for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    linelist = line.split(" ")


for word in linelist:
    if len(word) == int(wordLength):
        if len(word) in word_dict:
            word_dict[len(word)] = word_dict[len(word)].append(word)
        else:
            word_dict[len(word)] = word

print word_dict
```

Comment: What is the format of the dictionary.txt file?

Comment: it does look good to me. I assume that the words in the dictionary are always separated by spaces and not by commas, full stops or other symbols, am I right?

Comment: each word is on a line by itself

Comment: Then why are you `split`ting the lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time your first loop runs, it sets `linelist` to a new value, overwriting any old value.  After that first loop runs, `linelist` will contain only the `split` result from the last line of the file.  Every time you process one line of the file, you are throwing away whatever you did with the previous line.

If you want to build a list of all words in the dictionary file, you need to make a list and append to it on each iteration of your `for line in infile` loop.

Also, it doesn't make much sense to use `split` on each line if each line is just one word, since there will be no splitting to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Your second loop is not indented, so you run it only on the last value of `linelist`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in infile:
    line = line.strip()
    linelist = line.split(" ")
```

Every time you do `linelist = line.split(" ")`, that replaces the old linelist with words from just the last line. The list ends up only holding words from the last line. If you want words from the entire file, create a single linelist and extend it with new words:

```
linelist = []
for line in infile:
    # split with no argument splits on any run of whitespace, trimming
    # leading and trailing whitespace
    linelist += line.split()
#            ^ this means add the elements of line.split() to linelist
```

Since apparently every word is on its own line, though, you shouldn't even be using `split`:

```
words = [line.strip() for line in infile]
```